# PrimeSense Stream always waiting?

Tags: c++, qt, openni, primesense

I have problem that primesense carmine 1.08 and 1.09. before i did this project and worked well and then i format my pc and set up everthing again. now, OpenNI waiting for streams for infinit time. Any frame came:

```
    if( OpenNI::waitForAnyStream (m_streams,1,&changedIndex,2) == STATUS_OK ){

        con<<"Waiting";

        con<<OpenNI::getExtendedError();

    }else{

        con<<"Wait Failed";

    }
```

code is waiting here long long time ...
always tell Waiting with no error

any solution internet i have found

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have resolved this problem. now frame is streaming.  the basis problem is Change Video Mod.

When I change the video resolution mod, Code is waiting for frame and after any frame captured

My Ubuntu 12.04 crashed and I backed up my project before. format system and configuring every thing again(QT, Cuda, PrimeSense )... All toolkit works well but Prime Sense not. All seetings are same before ubuntu crashed.

At this point i can't understand anything_